# Evaluate boolean environment variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

How can I evaluate if a env variable is a boolean True, in Python? Is it correct to use:

```
if os.environ['ENV_VAR'] is True:
      .......
```

Comment: Environment variables can never be a boolean, they are always a string (or not present).

Comment: So, I should write: if os.environ['ENV_VAR'] == 'true': ..... right?

Comment: That depends on the semantics of that specific environment variable. They are only strings, but programs can of course endow specific strings with some special meaning, like "truth". Whether that's "true". "True", "TRUE", "yes", or "1" depends on the application.

Comment: `os.environ.get('ADT_email_send',str(False))=='True'`

Answer (score 153, accepted):

## Option 1

I think this works well:

```py
my_env = os.getenv("ENV_VAR", 'False').lower() in ('true', '1', 't')
```

It allows: things like `true`, `True`, `TRUE`, `1`, `"1"`, `TrUe`, `t`, `T`, ...

Update: After I read the commentary of Klaas, I updated the original code `my_env = bool(os.getenv(...` to `my_env = os.getenv(...` because `in` will result in a `bool` type

---

## Option 2

UPDATE:
After the @MattG commentary, I added a new solution that raises an error for entries like `ttrue` instead of returning `False`:

```py
# ...
import os
# ...

def get_variable(name: str, default_value: bool | None = None) -> bool:
    true_ = ('true', '1', 't')  # Add more entries if you want, like: `y`, `yes`, `on`, ...
    false_ = ('false', '0', 'f')  # Add more entries if you want, like: `n`, `no`, `off`, ...
    value: str | None = os.getenv(name, None)
    if value is None:
        if default_value is None:
            raise ValueError(f'Variable `{name}` not set!')
        else:
            value = str(default_value)
    if value.lower() not in true_ + false_:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid value `{value}` for variable `{name}`')
    return value in true_

# ...

my_env1 = get_variable("ENV_VAR1")
my_env2 = get_variable(name="ENV_VAR2") # Raise error if variable was not set
my_env3 = get_variable(name="ENV_VAR3", default_value=False) # return False if variable was not set
```

Comment: You can add to the list `['true', '1']` other options, like: `['true', '1', 'yes', 'y', 't']`

Comment: the use of `bool` in the above example is superfluous... `a in b` is always a boolean anyway

Comment: @KlaasvanSchelven, True, you are right, I will update. Thanks

Comment: The problem with this, is that if a typo is made setting the environment variable to say "ttrue" , this will not raise an exception. I think it is rare that for environment variable parsing, where you control the behavior of your code you don't want strong validation and are happy to accept values like "ttrue" being silently accepted as False.

Comment: Important bug I think: `value in true_` must be changed to `value.lower() in true_`.

Answer (score 70):

All the same, but thats the most readable version for me:

```
DEBUG = (os.getenv('DEBUG', 'False') == 'True')
```

Here anything but `True` will evaluate to False. DEBUG is False unless explicitly set to `True` in ENV

Comment: I would make it
os.getenv('DEBUG', 'False').lower() == 'true'

but awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 28):

I recommend using `strtobool` function

example:

```
DEBUG = strtobool(os.getenv("DEBUG", "false"))
```

You can check them in python documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool

Only one problem, they raise an error if you pass the wrong value

Code

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

print("Value: ", strtobool("false"))

print("Value: ", strtobool("Wrong value"))
```

Output

```
Value:  0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/util.py", line 319, in strtobool
    raise ValueError("invalid truth value %r" % (val,))
ValueError: invalid truth value 'wrong value'
```

Comment: From the package documentation: `Note: The entire distutils package has been deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.12`

Comment: [PEP 0632](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/): "[setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) is a better documented and well maintained enhancement based on distutils". But it marks [distutils.util.strtobool](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool) as deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

Highly recommend `environs`:

```
from environs import Env

env = Env()

MY_BOOL_VALUE = env.bool("MY_BOOL_VALUE", False)

if MY_BOOL_VALUE:
    print("MY_BOOL_VALUE was set to True.")
else:
    print("MY_BOOL_VALUE was either set to False or was not defined.")
```

Answer (score 8):

Neither of the ways you have will work. `os.environ['ENV_VAR']` alone will cause a `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist, and will return the value associated with the `'ENV_VAR'` if it does. In either case, you'll error out, or compare to `True` or `"true"` which will always result in `False` (unless the value associated with the environment variable happens to be `"true"`; but that isn't what you're after).

To check if a mapping contains a particular key, you would use `in`:

```
if 'ENV_VAR' in os.environ:
    # It contains the key
else:
    # It doesn't contain the key
```

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative that accepts either "false", "False", "true" or "True":

```
import os
import ast

def getenv_bool(name: str, default: str = "False"):
    raw = os.getenv(name, default).title()
    return ast.literal_eval(raw)
```

Comment: This is not as good of an idea as it may appear at first, because `ast.literal_eval` will give surprising and confusing (for the user) error messages such as `SyntaxError` and `IndentationError` with deep stack traces for bad inputs.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following to have more strict typing and support wider boolean variations in inputs

```py
import os

def getenv_bool(name: str, default: bool = False) -> bool:
    return os.getenv(name, str(default)).lower() in ("yes", "y", "true", "1", "t")
```

Usage :

```
feature_1=getenv_bool('FEATURE_1', False)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use the environs library mentioned above then [strtobool](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool) is perfect for this. The only problem is it is [deprecated](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/), there does not seem to be a replacement library anywhere, but luckily it is only a few lines of simple code with no dependencies. Just implement the code:

```
# Copied from distutils.util.strtobool, which is deprecated
def strtobool (val):
    """Convert a string representation of truth to true (1) or false (0).

    True values are case insensitive 'y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', and '1'.
    false values are case insensitive 'n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', and '0'.
    Raises ValueError if 'val' is anything else.
    """
    val = val.lower()
    if val in ('y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', '1'):
        return 1
    elif val in ('n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', '0'):
        return 0
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid truth value %r" % (val,))
```

Use it like this:

```
my_env_var_value = strtobool(os.getenv("ENV_VAR", "False"))
```

And **YES**, this will throw an error if the environment variable has some value that is neither true nor false. In the great majority of cases that is probably the best course of action.

Comment: confirmed works

Answer (score 2):

In Django, if you are using [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) also make sure you don't use DEBUG in the .env file as it will always default to `True` when we do `os.getenv("DEBUG")`. Use another variable e.g DEBUG_MODE. For example:

```
#.env 

DEBUG_MODE = False

#settings.py 

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG_MODE", False) == "True"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is parse values as JSON values:

```
import json
import os

def getenv(name, default="null"):
    try:
        return json.loads(os.getenv(name, default))
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        return name
```

The `try` is for cases when is not possible a direct conversion.

```
assert getenv("0") == 0
assert getenv("1.1") = 1.1
assert getenv("true") == True
assert getenv("Hello") = "Hello"
assert getenv('["list", "of", "strings"]') == ["list", "of", "strings"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python Version:
3.9.13 (main, May 27 2022, 17:01:00)

I used solution below and it works perfect;

In your env file;

```
SOMEHING_ENABLED=True
```

and use case in your python file;

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

if bool(strtobool(os.getenv('SOMEHING_ENABLED'))):
   # good to go.
```

Not: distutils will no longer work from version 3.12

Comment: distutils is deprecated: https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/

Comment: I determined my python version and tested code.

Comment: It will no longer work from version 3.12. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to require **strictly** that the environment variable is set to either `True` or `False`, and to not allow so many other squishy possibilities.  Also, if the variable isn't defined, I **want** an exception to be raised.

```py
assert(os.environ['MY_KEY'] in ('True', 'False'))

if os.environ['MY_KEY'] == 'True':
    # True
    pass
else:
    # False
    pass
```

This will raise a `KeyError` if `MY_KEY` is not defined, or raise an `AssertionError` if it's not set to either 'True' or 'False'.

If you are doing this frequently and therefore want a function, use this:

```py
def get_env_bool(key):
    """ Handles the case of a boolean environment variable
    """
    if not key in os.environ:
        raise KeyError(f"No environment variable {key}")

    if not os.environ[key] in ('True', 'False'):
        raise AssertionError(f"Key {key} is not proper boolean: {os.environ[key]}")

    return os.environ[key] == 'True'
```

Usage:

```py
if get_env_bool('MY_KEY'):
   ...
```

Answer (score -3):

The way I see it - why not use the builtin `bool()` which is similar to for instance `str()`

```
import os

my_boolean_env_var = bool(os.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR"))
```

Comment: This will return `True` for **any** value of `MY_ENV_VAR` because the boolean value of any string is `True` in Python.  Hence, also values like `False`, `false`, `0`, etc. will end up as `True`. Likely not what you want.